# Visual Studio erroneously including files from an external project in team explorer pending changes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, version-control

Ok... so I cannot find an answer to this anywhere, but I can't possibly be the first one to be experiencing this.  So I created a new solution with a new project (C# MVC) and when I added source control (TFS VC) it included some 385 files from an external project that has absolutely nothing to do with this new project.  In fact on my initial check in it gave me errors because it couldn't find some of the files it considered as part of the new project but were actually part of an existing external project. To work around this I excluded the 385 files from that folder to the external project, but this has to be referenced in the project somewhere and I want all references to this external project removed from my new project.  Please, can someone help me with this??? I can't find anything in google or on stackoverflow about this issue... maybe I am searching for the wrong thing?? Please help!!!

Comment: Try to look about .gitignore on google, seems like you are committing some files(compiled/references assemblies) that should not be committed.

Comment: I figured it out... My reference assembly had the old project in it.  I removed it and voila!  No more issues.  Thanks everyone!!!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... My reference assembly had the old project in it. I removed it and voila! No more issues. Thanks everyone!!!

Comment: Please mark your answer as a correct one so that others who meet the same issue will find your excellent solution to help them. We will appreciate your good job on helping us make the work better and easier.